# Get JWT in YARP before making route - is that possible?

Tags: .net-core, reverse-proxy, dotnet-httpclient, ms-yarp

I am currently trying to implement a proxy using `YARP`. I have read the documentation on `HttpClient`: https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/articles/http-client-config.html, but it doesn't seem that i can configure the HttpClient to use a `AddClientAccessTokenHandler` with a `AddAccessTokenManagement`. I would really like to tell `YARP` to pull a specific JWT before routing a request.

Is this possible with `YARP`? Or do i have to do something like:

```cs
app.MapGet("/", async (IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory,
   HttpContext context, Logger<Program> logger) =>
{
    httpClientFactory.CreateClient("CallBackWithJwt");
});
```

Where the client configured has been setup as one normally would do in the `IoC`?

Or maybe using s custom transform, where I pull a JWT and the add that to the header? https://microsoft.github.io/reverse-proxy/articles/transforms.html